# What ways are there to reformat/revalidate a tree of controls in Flex other than ValidateNow()

Tags: apache-flex, formatting

I am having problems with text with multiple lines not reformatting properly when I call `loadStyleDeclarations`. However if I load the same stylesheet TWICE then it correctly refreshes and reformats the text.

So what I want to do is refresh my control to get it to reformat the text. I've tried `ValidateNow()` and `ValidateDisplayList()` but neither seems to cause the correct kind of layout request.

I'm guessing `loadStyleDeclarations()` calls some other revalidation function, but i jsut cant find what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling invalidateProperties() and/or invalidateDisplayList() on your component. That should cause the component to be rerendered on a next screen update.

Comment: Turns out you have to call invalidateDisplayList() on the Text control itself. I assumed it was recursive at first, but then I thought I'd try it on the Text control itself which worked. Not even calling invalidateDisplayList() on the immediate container works. Thx